# How to make two multirow?

Tags: multirow

The merged rows are not vertically aligned, and the text overlaps with the next column. What should I do to fix this?

[image]

w_i should be in the second column. There are two multirows should be aligned vertically. One is Normal returns and another is Normal Mixture returns.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{c c c c} 
 \hline
 $\omega$ & M=4 & M=5 & M=6 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 \multirow{3}{*}{Normal returns}
 $\omega_1$ & 28.96 & 28.96 & 28.96 \\ 
 $\omega_2$ & 47.50 & 47.50 & 47.49 \\
 $\omega_3$ & 23.54 & 23.54 & 23.55 \\ [1ex] 
 \multirow{3}{*}{Normal Mixture returns}
 $\omega_1$ & 26.33 & 27.45 & 28.62 \\ 
 $\omega_2$ & 48.13 & 48.15 & 47.57 \\
 $\omega_3$ & 25.54 & 24.40 & 23.82 \\ [1ex] 
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: What should be aligned. I fear you misuse  `multirow`.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, it's now fixed

Comment: I don't understand what you try to obtain. Didn't test it yet, but this code shouldn't compile. The ω_i are supposed to be in the same columns as the multirow?

Comment: No, w_i should be in the second column. There are two multirows should be aligned vertically. One is Normal returns and another is Normal Mixture returns

Comment: This makes  5 columns. You declare 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow, makecell, booktabs}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
\toprule
& $\omega$ & M=4 & M=5 & M=6 \\
\midrule\midrule
\multirowcell{3}{Normal returns} &
$\omega_1$ & 28.96 & 28.96 & 28.96 \\
& $\omega_2$ & 47.50 & 47.50 & 47.49 \\
& $\omega_3$ & 23.54 & 23.54 & 23.55 \\ [1ex]
\multirowcell{3}{Normal Mixture\\ returns} &
$\omega_1$ & 26.33 & 27.45 & 28.62 \\
& $\omega_2$ & 48.13 & 48.15 & 47.57 \\
& $\omega_3$ & 25.54 & 24.40 & 23.82 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]